# Why is int(0.9) rounded to 0?

Tags: python, rounding

I noticed that when I type `int(0.9)` it becomes 0 instead of 1.

I was just wondering why Python wouldn't round the numbers.

Comment: It simply takes the integer value of the number. I guess because it a simpler calculation than round, and in my opinion less ambiguous.

Comment: The behaviour is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 3):

`int` does not perform rounding in the way you expect, it rounds to 0, the `round` function will round to the nearest whole number or places you provide.

```
>>> int(0.9)
0
>>> int(-0.9)
0
>>> round(12.57)
13
>>> round(12.57, 1)
12.6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `int` function, it ignores decimal points and gives you integer part. So use `round` function if you want to round figures.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `round` function

Answer (score 2):

> If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.

Source: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 2):

Simple: because int() works as "floor" , it simply cuts of instead of doing rounding. Or as "ceil" for negative values.

You want to use the *round()* function instead.

Comment: Rounding down to 0 would be a `floor()` not a `ceil()`

Comment: @NickA: It behaves like `floor` for positive inputs and `ceil` for negative inputs.

Comment: Thanks. And fixed. This is one of the few occasions where my knowledge of the English language keeps falling apart regularly. No idea why...